# NTP time sync not working in a DOMU Centos 5.5 server

Tags: xen, centos5, ntp, ntpd

I have a Xen Centos 5.5 server with ntpd working in virtual server.

NTP time sync seems not working.

I have disabled any firewall.

my `grep -i ntpd /var/log/messages` output:

```
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17635]: ntpd 4.2.2p1@1.1570-o Sat Dec 19 00:56:13 UTC 2009 (1)
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: precision = 1.000 usec
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface wildcard, 0.0.0.0#123 Disabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface wildcard, ::#123 Disabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface eth0, fe80::216:36ff:fe5e:53f3#123 Enabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface lo, ::1#123 Enabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface lo, 127.0.0.1#123 Enabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: Listening on interface eth0, 192.168.0.100#123 Enabled
Apr  1 16:15:47 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: kernel time sync status 0040
Apr  1 16:16:15 posadadelpuerto ntpd[17636]: frequency initialized 0.000 PPM from /var/lib/ntp/drift
```

Thanks for any help

roberto

Comment: Is it competing with NTP on DOM0.  All the instructions I have seen suggest not running NTP on virtual clients.

Answer (score 1):

By default the time of (pv) DomUs is linked against the time of the Dom0.
So get your time right on the Dom0 and don't bother about ntp on the (para-virtualized) DomUs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the output from `ntpq -p`?

Is there a chance your NTP queries are getting blocked by an external firewall?  That can still stop things, even if your local one is turned off.

Comment: ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
====================================================================
 core-vgg-1-lo0. 192.43.244.18    2 u   49   64    7   18.766  -26011. 4077.76
 core01.ses.net. 146.164.48.5     2 u   47   64    7   24.993  -26013. 4129.70

Answer (score 0):

I too had many ntp time sync issues with CentOs 5.5 on a virtual.  Here are the changes I made to get it working:

/boot/grub/grub.conf: add the notsc divider=10 switches

```
title CentOS (2.6.18-194.32.1.el5)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet notsc divider=10 
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-194.32.1.el5.img
```

/etc/ntp.conf: the minpoll/maxpoll settings are a bit agressive, so you may want to increase them.

```
tinker panic 0
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict default kod nomodify notrap
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10
```